# Python OpenCV VideoWriter slows down at around 3000 write()

Tags: performance, python-2.7, opencv

I am creating a video from 5100 full size images (each about 5000 X 3000 px) using OpenCV and Python.  Works great, however, at around image 3000 (with the AVI file at about 160 MB) the write() method slows down significant.

I'm cropping the image, and then I'm resizing before I write.  I've put a lot of timing code below.

CPU isn't the issue... lots of disk space... Has anyone seen this before?  (I've searched high and low)  I've been looking for memory leaks, but the code is too simple for that.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2, glob, time

files = glob.glob("./pics/*.JPG")

video = cv2.VideoWriter('test.avi',cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('m', 'p', '4', 'v'),120,(1920,1080))   

print "INDEX,  IMREAD,   CROP_IMG, RESIZE,   WRITE,    TOTAL"

for idx, file in enumerate(files):
   offset=idx/500  #just an offset to make sure that it reflects my real world.
   start = time.time()
   img = cv2.imread(file)
   imread_dur = time.time() - start

   start = time.time()
   crop_img = img[1000+offset:2050+offset, 500-offset:2370-offset] 
   crop_dur = time.time() - start

   start = time.time()
   resized_image = cv2.resize(crop_img, (1920, 1080))
   resize_dur = time.time() - start 

   start = time.time()
   video.write(resized_image)   
   write_dur = time.time() - start

   print "%5d,  %3.6f, %3.6f, %3.6f, %3.6f, %3.6f " % (idx,imread_dur, crop_dur, resize_dur, write_dur, imread_dur+crop_dur+resize_dur+write_dur)

video.release()
```

At around the 2900th image, it goes from about 200ms to video.write() to around 2000ms or more per image.  It feels like a buffer problem on the output video file, but nothing seems configurable.  (The CPU goes from almost a full core to ~3% as the write() slows down.)  At 3000, it is taking 13s for a write()

```
INDEX,  IMREAD,   CROP_IMG, RESIZE,   WRITE,    TOTAL
...
2847,  0.232032, 0.004127, 0.015886, 0.214999, 0.467044 
2848,  0.233260, 0.003745, 0.013973, 0.214703, 0.465681 
2849,  0.228818, 0.003882, 0.016408, 0.251602, 0.500710
...
3096,  0.238894, 0.003780, 0.013936, 13.183812, 13.440422 
3097,  0.253249, 0.004052, 0.015534, 13.668831, 13.941666
```

I've looked under the covers and nothing is popping up.  Anyone seen this?

Comment: I'm also seeing a slow down in much the same way. For my use case I was able to simply start a new output video every 40 seconds, so problem avoided. Would be great to know if anyone has a solution though.